# Auto Add Document to DocuSign Salesforce Using Custom Button

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, docusignapi

I'm using a DocuSign custom button. I have the document Id of the document I want added into docusign, on my object. Is there a way to automatically add the document using that Id?

The use case is, I'd like my user to hit the send via docusign button, and already have the document and the docusign envelop configured. If the document isn't there, they have to search for it.

Comment: Is it the same document for each person? You may want to consider just using a template and assign the template with the custom button (this would also automatically place tags as well if needed)

Comment: No. It's a quote document that has been generated dynamically. The quote document object has the ID of the document. I'd like to use that ID to automatically add that dynamic document to the standard DocuSign process in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

On the object you are having you dosign functionality,if that object has any attachments then it will take automatically those attachments and move in to the envelope page.I think you need a custom button to add attachment to the related object than that attachment will get added automatucally.After cilcking send with docusign button you will able to see those attachments.